# Lockout an user during change password

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

suppose I am the administator. I want to reset the password for an user.(Asp.net web form).
Before I change the password, I want to block the user login the web since in theory he/she can login change the password as well.

I am thinking to set IsLockedOut "true", but I heard that it is read only in database.
Is there any way to kick out the guy?
I mean that if the username is "test", I want to prevent "test" login during my opertional period.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
if (user.IsLockedOut == false)
{
   // kick out user
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: elaborate on "kick out the guy"

Comment: do you have access to the database? can you change the username to `test_reset` to prevent `test` from logging in?

Comment: I can change username for a moment and change it back again. But is it the best way?

Comment: What ways do you have available?

Comment: Letting your user know that maintenance is taking place would be nice.

Comment: @Love When you say "but I heard that it is read only in database", do you mean just the builtin `membership` functions or the actual DB? As the actual DB will be writeable to anyone with permissions (just tried it via SQL Management Studio).

Comment: @Love RemarkLima brings up a great point. This is why my answer is more focused on nipping the issue in the bud, rather than finding an elaborate way to keep your user out at all cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write your own method to access the database, say you're using the default ASP.NET memebership provider on a MS SQL server, you can access the `aspnet_Membership` table.

In here you can change the `IsLockedOut` or `IsApproved` to False / 0 while you work, then back again once you're done.

This can be a one button in a web GUI and you'll just need to usernames mapped to their `UserId`, but as said you'll need to write your own methods to access these tables in your database.

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" is opinionated, but here's how I would do it based on what you are asking. I would change `test`'s username to `test_reset` (or similar) during your operational period. The end-user, `test`, will not be able to login using his username (and as the end-user, will not know what his username was changed to) during your operational period.  After the period ends, change the username back to the original.

**GENERAL NOTE**: As long as you are admin, and have access, I would dig into the nuts and bolts, and not rely on a web GUI to do so.....